# Angular 4 observable to sql connection infomessage in Asp.core app

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, observable

im using ASP.core 2 with angular 4 to create a simple that will display the progress of a store procedure. I have the stored procedure send information to the web api controller method that called it. Im trying to find a way to use my client side observable subscribe to this output in order to display the progress as the data is coming in